# oauth.io node sdk - dynamic provider

Tags: node.js, express, oauth.io

I'm using the oauth.io node sdk for server side authentication and I want to authorise multiple providers on my app, I'm just wondering if there is a way of doing it without having to create a separate endpoint for each one.

Something like this is what I'm after but the authorisation function doesn't seem to work when wrapped in a container function.

```
app.get('/signin', function(req, res){
  OAuth.auth(req.param.provider, 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/redirect')
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Found answer thanks to thyb in this post

https://github.com/oauth-io/sdk-node/issues/14

```
app.get('/signin/:provider', function(req, res) {
  OAuth.auth(req.param.provider, 'http://localhost:8080/oauth/redirect')(req, res);
});
```